# How can I avoid these if statement issues on python

Tags: python, if-statement

I had a problem with the code that each time I select Category 2/3/4 it tells me that I didn't define any Variables in the code took so long to solve this problem but it remains' the same but with the cat 3/4 but this time it will give me another categories input. I dont know if it was related to any of the Global-Local Variables.

```
print("Welcome to NCPA & Co.")

print("                         ")

#Budget

print("Whats your budget :")


print(""" 1. Less than 100K

 2. between 100K & 499K

 3. between 500K & 999K

 4. between 1  M & 2.9M

 5. Greater Than   3  M    
  """)


Bud = int(input("Select from 1 - 5: "))

print(" ")


#Car's_Category


print("     Select your car's category           ")


print("________________________________________________________________")
print("|               |              |               |               |")
print("|  1.Economy    |  2.ELECTRIC  |   3.Sport     |   4.Luxury    |")
print("|_______________|______________|_______________|_______________|")


#input

Cat = int(input("Select from 1 - 4: "))


# Category 1

if (Cat == 1):

 print("Category : Economy ")

 print(""" Your Prefered brand
  1. Toyota
  2. Honda 
  3. Nissan
  4. Mitsubishi
  5. Kia""")
 print(" ")

 Cat1 = int(input("Select 1 - 5: "))

# Category 2
elif (Cat == 2):
 print("Category : Electric")
 print(""" Your prefered brand
  1. Tesla
  2. Mersedes
  3. Hummer""")
 print(" ")



# Category3:
elif (Cat == 3):
 print("Category : Sport")
 print(""" Your Prefered category
  1. Ford
  2. Mclaren
  3. Chevrolet
  4. Dodge""")
 print(" ")

 Cat3 = int(input("Select 1 - 4: "))


# Category 4
elif (Cat == 4):
 print("Category : Luxury")
 print(""" Your Prefered category
  1. Rolls Royse
  2. Bentley
  3. Range Rover
  4. Maserati""")

 Cat4 = int(input("Select 1 - 3: "))


else:

 print("")


#Category-1 (Toyota)

if(Cat1 == 1):

      print(""" Choose Your model...
      ___________________________
      |____|__Name____|__Price__|
      |  1 | Corolla  |  75,000 |
      |  2 | Avalon   |  60,000 |
      |  3 | Prius    |  40,000 |
      |____|__________|_________|
      """)


elif(Cat1 == 2): #Category-1 (Honda)
  print(""" Choose Your model...
      ___________________________
      |____|__Name____|__Price__|
      |  1 | Accord   |  35,000 |
      |  2 | HXF      |  70,000 |
      |  3 | Civic    |  90,000 |
      |__4_|__________|_________|
      """)


elif(Cat1 == 3): #Category-1 (Nissan)
  print(""" Choose Your model...
      ___________________________
      |____|__Name____|__Price__|
      |  1 | Altima   |  75,000 |
      |  2 | Sentra   |  60,000 |
      |  3 | Versa    |  40,000 |
      |____|__________|_________|
      """)


elif(Cat1 == 4): #Category-1 (Mitsubishi)
  print(""" Choose Your model...
      ___________________________
      |____|__Name____|__Price__|
      |  1 | Lancer   |  75,000 |
      |  2 | Toppo    |  60,000 |
      |  3 | Mirage   |  40,000 |
      |____|__________|_________|
      """)


elif(Cat1 == 5): #Category-1 (Kia)
  print(""" Choose Your model...
      ___________________________
      |____|__Name____|__Price__|
      |  1 | picanto  |  75,000 |
      |  2 | Forte    |  60,000 |
      |  3 | Rio      |  40,000 |
      |____|__________|_________|
      """)

elif(Cat1 >= 6):
  print("Invaled input please run again")

#Category-2 8
Cat2 = int(input("Select 1 - 3: "))    
if(Cat2 == 1): #Category-2 (Tesla)    
  print(""" Choose Your model...
      ___________________________
      |____|__Name____|__Price__|
      |  1 | Model 3  | 195,600 |
      |  2 | Model S  | 477,000 |
      |  3 | Model X  | 330,000 |
      |____|__________|_________|
      """)
    
elif (Cat2 == 2): #Category-2 (Mercedes)
  print(""" Choose Your model...
      ___________________________
      |____|__Name____|__Price__|
      |  1 |    EQS   | 308,000 |
      |  2 |    EQA   | 280,000 |
      |  3 |    EQC   | 320,000 |
      |____|__________|_________|
      """)    

elif (Cat2 == 3): #Category-2 (Volvo)
  print(""" Choose Your model...
      ___________________________________
      |____|__Name_____|____Price_______|
      |  1 |   XC40    |   120,000      |
      |  2 |   290     |   150,000      |
      |  3 |   XC90    |   200,000      |
      |____|___________|________________|
      """)        

elif():
  print("Invalid Input")
 
#Category-3 (Sport)
elif(Cat3 == 1): #Category-3 (Mclaren)
  print(""" Choose Your model...
      _____________________________
      |____|__Name____|___Price___|
      |  1 |   720S   | 1,247,200 |
      |  2 |   P1     | 2,000,000 |
      |  3 |   Senna  | 5,000,000 |
      |  4 |   Artura | 1,000,000 |
      |____|__________|___________|
      """)

  Cat3_S1 = input(int("Select from 1 - 4"))      

elif(): #Category-3 (Ford)
   print(""" Choose Your model...
      ___________________________
      |____|__Name____|__Price__|
      |  1 |  F-150   | 288,000 |
      |  2 |  Mustang | 477,000 |
      |  3 |  GT500   | 195,000 |
      |____|__________|_________|
      """)        
elif (): #Category-3 (Dodge)
   print(""" Choose Your model...
      ________________________________
      |____|______Name_____|__Price__|
      |  1 |   Challanger  | 310,000 |
      |  2 |   ChargerSR/T | 290,000 |
      |  3 |   HellCat     | 412,500 |
      |____|_______________|_________|
      """)        

elif (): #Category-3 (Chevrolet)
   print(""" Choose Your model...
      ___________________________
      |____|__Name____|___Price__|
      |  1 | Impala   | 225,000  |
      |  2 | Camaro   | 292,000  |
      |  3 | Corvette | 345,000  |
      |____|__________|__________|
      """)        

elif():    
  print("")        

#Category-4 (Luxury)    
elif (Cat4 == 1): #Category-4 (Rolls Royce)
  print("""  Choose Your model...
    _______________________________
    |____|___Name___|___Price_____|
    |  1 |  Wraith  | 1,260,000   |
    |  2 |  Ghost   | 1,310,000   |
    |  3 |  Phantom | 1,650,000   |
    |____|__________|_____________|            
  """)
    
elif (Cat4 == 2): #Category-4 (Bentley)
  print(""" Choose Your model...
      ______________________________________
      |____|____Name_________|____Price____|
      |  1 |  Flying Spur V8 |   950,000   |
      |  2 |  Continental    |   1,110,000 |
      |  3 |  Bentayga       |   2,000,000 |
      |____|_________________|_____________|
      """)    
elif (Cat4 == 3): #Category-4 (Range Rover)
  print(""" Choose Your model...
      ___________________________
      |____|__Name____|__Price__|
      |  1 | SE P360  | 580,000 |
      |  2 | HSE P400 | 640,000 |
      |  3 | HSE P530 | 710,000 |
      |____|__________|_________|
      """)
          
elif (Cat4 == 4): #Category-4 (Maserati)
  print(""" Choose Your model...
      _____________________________________
      |____|____Name_______|__Price_______|
      |  1 |   Levante     | 420,000      |
      |  2 |   Ghibli      | 425,000      | 
      |  3 |   Quattroporte| 565,000      |
      |____|_______________|______________|
      """)    
else:
  print("")
```

Comment: You haven't written code for category 3  : `elif (): #Category-3 (Dodge)` and also for 4. The code is incomplete.

Comment: @DevangSanghani I've added those line's immediately after posting, My main issue currently is Starting from line 114 which is Cat1. and as i try to proceed to any other variables it always shows that Cat1 is no defined

Comment: So, the thing is if someone choses other categories, Cat1 will not be populated which is in the if scope. You should rather have everything under single category all together.

Comment: There are too many IFs, you can modularize the code by putting them in different functions and calling them as needed.

Comment: So your recommendation is to add functions so I can call them instead of using If statements?

Comment: Added sample code as an answer. Remember to define the functions before in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Create functions based on categories, so as to separate the code. Like:

```
#input
Cat = int(input("Select from 1 - 4: "))
# Category 1
if (Cat == 1):

 print("Category : Economy ")

 print(""" Your Prefered brand
  1. Toyota
  2. Honda 
  3. Nissan
  4. Mitsubishi
  5. Kia""")
 print(" ")

 Cat1 = int(input("Select 1 - 5: "))
 get_cat1_details(Cat1) #<- Added a function

# Category 2
elif (Cat == 2):
 print("Category : Electric")
 print(""" Your prefered brand
  1. Tesla
  2. Mersedes
  3. Hummer""")
 print(" ")

 Cat2 = int(input("Select 1 - 3: "))
 get_cat2_details(Cat2) #<- Added a function

# Category3:
elif (Cat == 3):
 print("Category : Sport")
 print(""" Your Prefered category
  1. Ford
  2. Mclaren
  3. Chevrolet
  4. Dodge""")
 print(" ")

 Cat3 = int(input("Select 1 - 4: "))
 get_cat3_details(Cat3)  #<- Added a function  

# Category 4
elif (Cat == 4):
 print("Category : Luxury")
 print(""" Your Prefered category
  1. Rolls Royse
  2. Bentley
  3. Range Rover
  4. Maserati""")

 Cat4 = int(input("Select 1 - 3: "))
 get_cat4_details(Cat4) #<- Added a function

else:

 print("Invalid Category")
```

Put relevant codes in the relevant functions:

```
def get_cat1_details(c1):
  .......
def get_cat2_details(c2):
 ...
def get_cat3_details(c3):
 .....
def get_cat4_details(c4):
....
```